# Type checking on return type

Tags: typescript

I have following piece of code:

```js
interface Box<T> {
  value: T | null;
}

function foo<T>(b: Box<T>, defaultVal: T): T {
  return b.value || defaultVal;
}

const s: string | null = null;
const t = foo({ value: s }, { value: "def" });
console.log(t);
```

Why does this compile? I expected to get type error on second argument.

Comment: Could you please add more details, why you are expected the error on `defaultVal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because even though `s` has a `string | null` type signature, it's type is narrowed to `null` because of the assignment. You can see this if you hover over `s`. If you hover over `foo`, it shows `T` is chosen as `{value: string}`, which makes the application type correct.

For an `s` that has an actual union type, you'll get the expected error:

```
const test = (s: string | null) => {
  const t = foo({ value: s }, { value: "def" }); // Error, as expected
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsAeAeAKgPmQG8BYAKGWQDc4AbAVwgC5ldkAfZEe22gbnIBfcuRj0QCMMHQhkMdOjz4AFACMWGHAQA0yACYR4PMADU6LXAEoLxcpSgQw9KLNUA6GgxTtOBo7VM6ATJhMnIEGQBnMGRIlmioUABzDi4eWmQAXjTeYIiQaOQY7Pl0ZSJqOkZ45EFdCs9q5AAiP2bayzyo9FoIN1p0JOUwTpEyfMLIQuzlONiwRJAUzm5eSyzCUgpkCZjiuQVyyq8auuJjptbDdsFO5AB6e%20QAUSgodChdOEjkCEwABwgkggeiE5CAA)

Comment: Oh that seems bad.. `const s: string | null = null` compiles but `const s = null as string | null` doesn't. For someone from Java background, the first case looks totally wrong.

Comment: Coming from Java, you'll probably encounter more things that look wrong in TypeScript :-) Many of these are caused by the fact that TypeScript has a lot of pragmatic design choices to be able to type the unwieldy underlying JavaScript language and its common patterns.